# Instagram Graph API Video & Reels

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api, instagram-reels

Recently, on the 21st of May Instagram [released an update](https://www.makeuseof.com/what-happened-to-igtv-on-instagram/#:%7E:text=Instagram%20ditched%20the%20IGTV%20tab,Instagram%27s%20video%20format%2C%20Instagram%20Video) regrading IGTV, Videos, and Reels.

I used to get my user's media with the help of the Graph API, BUT after the update, new videos which are created are considered a Reel.
Note - users have to be creators \ business accounts.

To quote Facebook "Reels are not supported" I know...

The main issue is that when I query the endpoints

> POST /{ig-user-id}/media

or

> GET /{ig-user-id}/business_discovery

of a certain user, no new videos returned from the API.

My question is:

Has anybody encountered the same problem and maybe has some workarounds?
Or we should just wait for an API update, which i saw we have v14 now , but without any new features regarding videos and reels

Thanks!

Comment: The documentation says that reels should just automatically appear in the endpoints we're already using but I'm not seeing any objects returned with media_type=REELS

Comment: Update: they fixed it 
reels are returning with media type = video 
and media_product_type is REEL.